# Derived class used as a model in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a class in a different project and want to extend that class to another project with Entity Framework. Is this possible? Will it generate a table with the properties from the base class?

Example:

`IUser.cs` (from project with no Entity Framework)

```
public interface IUser
{
     string Username { get; init; }
     string Password { get; init; }
}
```

`User.cs` (from project with no Entity Framework)

```
public class User : IUser
{
     string Username { get; init; }
     string Password { get; init; }
}
```

`UserDB.cs` (from project with Entity Framework)

```
public class UserDB : User 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Short answer: should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In EF Core this works automatically.  In EF for legacy .NET projects you have to map the inherited properties inside of `OnModelCreating()` like this:

```cs
            var mapping = modelBuilder.Entity<UserDB>();
            mapping.Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
            });
```

Otherwise, the database table will not store the properties of the `User` class

Answer (score 1):

Yes, EF would see `UserDB` as a class that had the properties: Id, Username and Password.